# while doing maven clean install i am getting this kind of error in eclipse smart home

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

while doing maven clean install i am getting this kind of error in eclipse smart home

" Failed to execute goal on project eclipsesmarthome-incubation: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.eclipse.smarthome:eclipsesmarthome-incubation:pom:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.smarthome.products:org.eclipse.smarthome.repo:zip:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]"

can any one help me out

Comment: have you downloaded that dependency into your local repository?

Answer (score 1):

The artifact

```
org.eclipse.smarthome.products:org.eclipse.smarthome.repo:zip:0.10.0-SNAPSHOT
```

is not available. This could have several reasons:

- if this artifact is supposed to come from a Maven repository on the internet, make sure that this Maven repository is added to the setttings.xml
- if you are behind a proxy/firewall, make sure your Maven can go through it.
- if you just downloaded the artifact, you need to add it to your local repository with the help of the Maven install plugin.